# Counting number of steps till a number gets to 1

Tags: python, numbers, counting, operations

The goal of this function is to count the number of steps it takes a number to get to 1 after performing operations. The number you put into the function is divided by 2 if the number is even, and tripled and increased by 1 if the number is odd. These operations are performed on the number until it reaches one. For example, if you start out with the number 3 it would go through these steps: 3 >10 >5 >16 >8 >4 >2 >1 the function would need to return the number "8" because it took 8 steps for 3 to get to 1 after dividing even numbers and multiplying by 3 and adding 1 to odd numbers.

Here is my code so far. I understood how to have my function return the first step (Example: I could have 3 return 10 and 6 return 3) but I can't figure out how to have my function count the number of steps it took to reach 1.

```
def collatz_counts(n):
    total = 0
    while n > 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n =(n // 2)
            total += 1

        elif n % 2 == 1:
            n = (3 * n + 1)
            total += 1
            return total
```

Comment: I didn't review your logic, but your `return total` should be outside your while.

Comment: That looks like only 7 steps...

Comment: @AChampion its 8 counting the first step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust the code to make it return after the `while` loop. Otherwise, it will return too early if it meet odd number.

Additionally, `total += 1` is done in both case; you can move it out of `if .. elif ..` block.

```
def collatz_counts(n):
    total = 0
    while n > 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n =(n // 2)
        elif n % 2 == 1:
            n = (3 * n + 1)
        total += 1  # <---
    return total  # <---
```

BTW, `collatz_counts(3)` will return 7. You need to adjust initial `total` value to 1 to get 8.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri, Thank you for point it. I fixed the indentation.

Comment: Thank you so much @falsetru especially for the advice of setting the total equal to one